# Pokémon GO APK file contains malware

Tags: mobile

In some countries, the game isn't launched officially yet, but this is getting vastly popular as people are downloading from links containing APK files. I suspect that it is possible that the file contains malwares. How to check for it?  What permissions that the app asks should I suspect?

Comment: if it is not from the official store, then it is suspect

Comment: FYI: An app with no permissions requirements can still contain malware.

Comment: verify signature?

Comment: @JamesLu How? Maybe we could give OP a step-to step description of how to do this.

Comment: @Fiksdal just a wild guess from a theoretical standpoint

Comment: @JamesLu Yes, it makes sense. Android actually does something like that with Google Play for sideloaded apps. It's connected to updates. But I don't understand fully how it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Alexander pointed out in the comments, checking permissions alone is not a reliable way to determine whether an APK is trustworthy or not. Especially not for an app like Pokémon Go, which is going to require a wide array of permissions in any case.

If you are forced to download an app from an unofficial source, one of the smartest things to do is to get it from a *trusted source*. The best thing would be if you had a real-world friend or family member with a Google Play account linked to a country where the app is released. That person could install the app from Google Play, copy the APK from their phone, and send it to you. This way you know you have a real, untampered APK, just like the original developers distributed it. Obviously, it is not often that you have such a friend, so on to the next option.

[Apkmirror.com](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/niantic-inc/pokemon-go/pokemon-go-0-29-2-release/pokemon-go-0-29-2-android-apk-download/) is run by the same people behind AndroidPolice.com, one of the biggest Android news websites. All uploads are manually vetted and approved, and only free apps are allowed so you won't find any 'cracked' APK or 'warez'.

As you already have the Play Store installed, only an APK signed with the same key as the currently installed version will be able to upgrade the app so this is an extra verification of the APK you download. Therefore, if you download the app from Apkmirror.com you should be safe.

APKmirror [use both MD5 and SHA1](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/11/19/meet-apk-mirror/) and they have gradually built up a solid reputation over years. I'm not aware of any confirmed case of a compromised APK on their site. Of course, it may plausibly still happen, but even the Play Store is not completely safe from all malware. APKmirror manually checks each APK.

[Attribution](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/135736/131868) for part of the section on apkmirror.com.

Comment: APKMirror in addition offer an MD5 checksum for the download. Grab an MD5 checker from Google Play and point it at the freshly downloaded file. The hash on the website and the one produced by the MD5 checker should match. Of course, you are still trusting that the APKMirror site has not been compromised.

Comment: MD5 is no longe secure - researchers have made a fast program that replicates an MD5 hash given as input some data the collision should start with. -1

Comment: @JamesLu Thanks for pointing that out. I've removed the part about MD5 from the answer.

Comment: @Fiksdal you still can't trust APKmirror if you have no secure signature

Comment: When you get an apk from someone else how do you know it doesn't install a trojan together with the game and they didn't notice?

Comment: @JamesLu APKmirror [also uses SHA1](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/11/19/meet-apk-mirror/) and they have gradually built up a solid reputation over years. I'm not aware of any confirmed case of a compromised APK on their site. Of course, it may happen, but even the Play Store is not completely safe from malware. APKmirror manually checks each APK.

Comment: @Philipp Because the other person would have gotten it directly from the Play Store.

Comment: @Fiksdal please mention that then. this is information security, not superuser

Comment: @JamesLu Sure, I've added it to OP. Thanks for the feedback. SE is all about collaboration.

Comment: you have my upvote now :) side note: although SHA1 is not secure theoretically and shouldn't be used, no one has done such attack I described in the previous comment on SHA1

Comment: @Fiksdal new SHA1 certs on the web are already not allowed, and they are to be 100% banned (any site using a SHA1 cert will be blocked by modern browsers) in 2017 (maybe earlier)

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC Interesting.

Comment: @Fiksdal changed it to flip upside down

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC Oh, ok :) For a moment I thought it might have been [something like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279526/321647).

Comment: @Fiksdal it used to be just CrazyPython, but considering my generated image, I decided to add some flavor to it.

Comment: also, check out my profile (its funny)

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC Haha, yeah, nice profile.

Answer (score 1):

TheHackerNews reported this to be true [here](http://thehackernews.com/2016/07/download-pokemon-go-android-iphone.html).

> Security firm Proofpoint has discovered the malicious app, or APK, that has been infected with [DroidJack](http://www.welivesecurity.com/2015/10/30/using-droidjack-spy-android-expect-visit-police/) – a Remote Access Tool (RAT) that can hack any Android device by opening a silent backdoor for hackers.

And they also talked about Pokemon GO granting itself full access to your google account [here](http://thehackernews.com/2016/07/uh-oh-pokemon-go-grants-itself-full.html).

> Adam Reeve labeled the game "malware," saying that Pokémon GO is a "huge security risk" as the game, for some reason, grants itself "full account access" to your Google account when you sign into the app via Google on iPhone or iPad.

With that in mind, i would follow Fiksdal's tips to be on the safe side.

Comment: The Google full access thing has been fixed now - v1.01 for iOS doesn't ask for full permissions.

Comment: @Fiksdal Yes you are right, the game are distributed via third parties who inject malicious code into the game, but since the game only released in so few countries, a lot of people reside to download the game through these third parties. And the question also said "In some countries, the game isn't launched officially yet".

Comment: @Fiksdal , I was looking at file permissions of Pokemon Go in one of my friend's phone. There was one permission which was : "Write/Delete to USB storage". Isn't it suspicious?

Comment: @one Where did your friend download Pokémon Go from? Where did he/she download it? I have installed it from APKmirror, and on my phone it needs to "read/modify/delete the contents of your SD card". Is that what you're talking about? Looking at Pokémon Go at Google Play, I can see that the official APK also needs access to device storage.

Comment: @Fiksdal yes, it was an apkmirror link. I checked and as also as you mentioned that official APK also needs access to device storage, it is settled.